# How to convert specific type to generic type (all built-in type)?

Tags: generics, types, rust

I want to return specific type to generic type, all are built-in type, so it can't impl From for u32 { ... }

```
fn fn1<T>() -> T {
    let a = 123u64;
    a as T
    // ^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
}

fn main() {
    let a = fn1::<u32>();
    dbg!(a);
}
```

any good way ?

Comment: This looks like a [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's probably a sane solution for your real problem. What is it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should note that what you do is fundamentally unsafe as you're fitting a larger type in a smaller one.

Then, you should use traits to specify that your generic function applies to types which *can* be converted:

```rust
use std::convert::{TryFrom, TryInto};

fn fn1<T: TryFrom<u64>>() -> T {
    let a = 123u64;
    a.try_into().unwrap_or_else(|_| {
        panic!("maybe improve the behavior here");
    })
}

fn main() {
    let a = fn1::<u32>();
    dbg!(a);
}
```

Comment: TryFrom not subject to the orphan rule?

Comment: @Anunaki I don't follow what you mean with this comment. You're not implementing the trait, just using it. And you could implement it on your own types if you'd need it.

Answer (score -3):

I found a way, but I'm not sure there's a big problem:

```
fn fn1<T: Default + Copy>() -> T {
    let mut a = 123456789u64;
    let t = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<&mut u64, &mut T>(&mut a) };
    *t
}

fn main() {
    let a = fn1::<u32>();
    dbg!(a);
}
```

Comment: Doing this for any type is *very* unsafe. You're going around the type system and doing unsound assumption about the internal storage of any type.